# reducing junk in gdb print

Tags: c++, stl, gdb

I am using gdb 7.2 with the configuration by Dan Marinescu that allows printing STL vectors strings, etc. (pstring, pvector, etc)
It doesn't seem very good.  So looking at one of the answers below, I cleaned out and used the pretty printers available in 7.0 and better.

In order to do so, I put the following in my .gdbinit

```
python
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, '/home/me/gdb_printers/python')
from libstdcxx.v6.printers import register_libstdcxx_printers
register_libstdcxx_printers (None)
end
set print elements 0
```

The instructions say to download the code from svn into /home/me/gdb_printers/python but that was a while ago.  I noticed that there was code is in gdb 7.3.  So I deleted the above and the basics work but stl does not.  Here's an object containing a string:

{a = 2, b = 97 'a', c = 2469135780247, d = 1.1363636363636362, e = {
    static npos = 18446744073709551615, 
    _M_dataplus = {> = {<__gnu_cxx::new_allocator> = {}, }, _M_p = 0x602028 "foo"}}}

./gdb-7.3.50.20110526/gdb/data-directory/python/gdb:

In order to work with STL, I needed to download the code for the archer project:
svn co svn://gcc.gnu.org/svn/gcc/trunk/libstdc++-v3/python

and put it in the above directory, making sure all the other junk was gone, and it works beautifully.

Comment: Do you have a code snippet of what you have tried? You might be able to do this with a template helper for printing and specializations for the types you want customize.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want to do is addressed in GDB 7.0 and above with [Python pretty printers](http://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Pretty-Printing.html).

You don't need `pstring`, regular `print` [just works](http://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Pretty_002dPrinter-Example.html#Pretty_002dPrinter-Example) (for embedded strings too).

Comment: we have gdb 7.2.  The command: info pretty-print does not work.  The documentation is pretty sparse, and doesn't mention how to set this up.  Is it possible that by loading the older stuff our configuration is messed up?  How can I get a clean configuration in which I can see this working?  should I have an empty .gdbinit?

Comment: print doesn't work for STL objects, that is to say, it prints loads of junk for stl objects.  I added the instructions in my question for STL